# Issue with count and group by to get inner join with count of 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT s.username FROM `instagram_shop` s
INNER JOIN `instagram_shop_picture` p ON
s.id = p.shop_id 
WHERE COUNT(p.id) = 0
GROUP BY p.id
;
```

I essentially wanted to find all shops that doesn't have any pictures yet. I wanted to get the username of the shop. However the above query gives me `#1111 - Invalid use of group function` why is this?

Here's what the instagram_shop looks like:

[image]

and here's the instagram_shop_picture:

[image]

Comment: You can't use `where` to filter results of aggregate functions you need to use `having` also for your required username provide sample data set for your tables and schema also

Comment: and you must change inner join to left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things to correct here.

**`HAVING` for conditions related to Aggregate functions**

`Where` is for the filter to be applied before the data gets aggregated using Count, Min, Max, Sum, etc.

`Having` is to be used after the aggregation is done, and only on aggregation functions.

**Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` Or `EXISTS`**

When you use an `Inner Join`, you will only get rows from instagram_shop, and instagram_shop_picture.  To get rows that do not exist in instagram_shop_picture, you can use an `OUTER JOIN`, or use an `EXISTS`

```
SELECT s.username
FROM instagram_shop s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  instagram_shop_picture p 
    ON s.id = p.shop_id 
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0
```

OR

```
SELECT s.username
FROM instagram_shop s
Where Not Exists
(
    Select 1
    From instagram_shop_picture p 
    Where s.id = p.shop_id 
)
```

Comment: I wanted to find shops that has no entries in instagram_shop_picture, if that made any sense

Comment: To find the non-picture shops, you have to use a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN.

Comment: I think your 2nd solution after the OR worked.. also what if I wanted to append some string to s.username? Do I use CONCAT ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `CONCAT`

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` filters are executed against the data before aggregation occurs (aggregation being a GROUP BY or SUM() or AVG(), for instance). If you need to filter your results after aggregation you will need to use `HAVING`

```
SELECT s.username, count(p.id) 
FROM `instagram_shop` s
    LEFT JOIN `instagram_shop_picture` p ON
        s.id = p.shop_id 
GROUP BY s.username
HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 0;
```

It's important to note that `HAVING` can be an expensive procedure since the database has to return and aggregate all of your results before it is used. So if your returned results are HUGE, `HAVING` is going to churn for a while.

ADDED: As folks have pointed out, because of your schema, you need to use a LEFT JOIN here. Using an INNER JOIN causes you to drop records from your result where there are no pictures. Once that's done there will be no records before OR after aggregation where the count(p.id) = 0. So you get nothing back.

Seeing your schema you could also use:

```
SELECT s.username 
FROM `instagram_shop` s
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT shop_id, count(id) as countOfPictures FROM `instagram_shop_picture`) p ON
        s.id = p.shop_id 
WHERE p.countOfPictures IS NULL
```

This may actually reduce runtime since it involves aggregating on a smaller result from a single table (where the index can be taken into consideration by the DB). The derived table adds back some overhead, but overall you'll probably come out ahead.

Comment: I am not sure why, but that gives me 0 entry result. While I am prettty sure that it should at least give me one result

Comment: Use "LEFT JOIN" to add entries in 'instagram_shop' that are not found in 'instagram_shop_picture'

Comment: @adit exactly you are getting right results for correct results see the second part of my answer **Provide sample data and table definitions**, `JNevill`'s answer is correct for the error you have posted but it will not give you correct results

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid added the table definitions

Comment: Why would you want to count all pictures first.  That is quite possibly the much larger table - it would degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
Select *
From `instagram_shop` s Left Join `instagram_shop_picture` p On s.id = p.shop_id 
Where p.shop_id is null
```